# Function scope when used from outside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Supposedly we have an object with an arrow function in it like this:

```
obj: {
    key1: someValue,
    key2: (arg) => { $scope.close() }
}
```

We pass this object to a component ( with isolated scope ), whose controller has the implementation of close().

What happens is that $scope is undefined ( if not injected in the controller where it was declared) or the $scope of controller it was declared , thus close() is always undefined.

Ideally i want to clone the function to the target controller.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vaggelanos/uzau4n1m/9/)

Comment: Your forgot to pass `$scope`!

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uzau4n1m/10/

Comment: @funcoding in your example you just call new scope of component

Comment: @MaximShoustin You are right! my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Component's](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) controller use isolate scope only so you cannot pass `$scope` from one component controller to another.

in your example you can try:

```
myFn($scope)
```

and in `parentComponent` call `$ctrl.data`:

```
ctrl.obj = {
    key1: 'test',
    key2: (arg) => { console.log(arg.$ctrl.data); }
  }
```

<kbd>[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ydxyjk2p/)</kbd>

Comment: Works but i would prefer not to use rootscope since i m going to pass this function to a modal base controller i am using and want to pass it different functions per case. So with rootscope its going to get pretty messy. Thanks

Comment: @vsyk what about ` myFn($scope)` and `key2: (arg) => { console.log(arg.$ctrl.data); }`?